# Ramsey Theorem for the class ORD

Tags: set-theory, ramsey-theory, ordinal-numbers

Is it true that given a (definable) 2-coloring of the ORD (class of ordinals), $\chi:[ORD]^{2}\rightarrow\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$, there exists an unbounded $H\subseteq ORD$ which is homogenous, i.e., $\chi:\upharpoonright [H]^2$ is constantly 0 or 1?   `

In the above $[X]^2$ is the collection of *unordered* pairs from $X$.

Comment: You presumably meant not $ORD^2$ and $H\times H$ but the classes of **unordered** pairs from $ORD$ and $H$. I suspect you also intended to ask about provability rather than truth. I can give you an easy answer about truth: Yes, it's true (i.e., $ORD$ really is weakly compact). Unfortunately, that's just my opinion, and provability is another matter. It's surely not provable in the usual theories of sets and classes like NBG or MK.

Answer (score 12):

Ali Enayat and I have proved that with respect to *definable* classes, Ord is NOT weakly compact. In particular, we show, in every model of ZFC,

- there is a definable Ord-tree with no definable cofinal branch.
- there is a definable 2-coloring of a definable proper class, with no definable homogeneous proper class.
- there is a definable set-satisfiable $L_{\text{Ord},\omega}$-theory, which has no definable class model.

This result surprised me very much, since it shows that with respect to definable classes, we can prove that Ord fails to have a large cardinal property that reasonable people might have expected to hold true.

The article is now available:

- A. Enayat and J. D. Hamkins, [ZFC proves that the class of ordinals is not weakly compact for definable classes](http://jdh.hamkins.org/ord-is-not-definably-weakly-compact/), manuscript under review. ([arχiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02729), [blog post](http://jdh.hamkins.org/ord-is-not-definably-weakly-compact/))

Comment: We can reduce from the $V$-coloring to an Ord-coloring, if we know that there is a definable bijection of $V$ with Ord, but otherwise we seem really to need $V$ rather than Ord in that part.

Comment: So in my comment on the question, where I said "Yes, it's true," I should emphasize that I was taking the question very literally, with "definable" applying to the coloring but not to the homogeneous class $H$.

Comment: I can agree with that. If you imagine that Ord comes from a large cardinal in some kind of larger universe, then that is precisely what you'd expect.

Comment: I updated with links, now that the article is available.

Comment: Thanks for posting the article. Could one also prove this claim in the following way: Suppose for a contradiction that ORD is weakly compact for definable sets in $M\models ZFC$.  Then we can build a minimal type $p$ over $M$. Furthermore, $p$ can be used to build a conservative elementary end extension of $M$. However, this is a contradiction since models of ZFC do not have conservative elementary end extensions.

Comment: @SamDworetzky  Your outline is correct (sorry for the tardy reply; I only now saw your question). In the paper with Joel we provide a more direct proof.